# How to Order Output made from Specific Lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, class

*I am trying to create a sort(self) method inside my Hand class I am running into an issue because the regular sorted and .sort methods don't organize the values in the order of precedence I need*

**Current Output:**

```
d = Deck()
print(d)
print()
d.shuffle()
h = d.deal(5)
h.add(d.draw())
h.add(d.draw())
print(h)
h.sort()
print()
print(h)
2 C, 3 C, 4 C, 5 C, 6 C,
7 C, 8 C, 9 C, T C, J C,
Q C, K C, A C, 2 D, 3 D,
4 D, 5 D, 6 D, 7 D, 8 D,
9 D, T D, J D, Q D, K D,
A D, 2 H, 3 H, 4 H, 5 H,
6 H, 7 H, 8 H, 9 H, T H,
J H, Q H, K H, A H, 2 S,
3 S, 4 S, 5 S, 6 S, 7 S,
8 S, 9 S, T S, J S, Q S,
K S, A S

J S, 7 S, 9 D, A H, 2 C,
3 D, 5 D
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/n/card pract.py", line 144, in <module>
    h.sort()
  File "C:/User/card pract.py", line 121, in <module>
    return sorted(card, key= ordered.index)
builtins.ValueError: substring not found
```

**Outputs I Need:**

```
d = Deck()
print(d)
print()
d.shuffle()
h = d.deal(5)
h.add(d.draw())
h.add(d.draw())
print(h)
2 C, 3 C, 4 C, 5 C, 6 C,
7 C, 8 C, 9 C, T C, J C,
Q C, K C, A C, 2 D, 3 D,
4 D, 5 D, 6 D, 7 D, 8 D,
9 D, T D, J D, Q D, K D,
A D, 2 H, 3 H, 4 H, 5 H,
6 H, 7 H, 8 H, 9 H, T H,
J H, Q H, K H, A H, 2 S,
3 S, 4 S, 5 S, 6 S, 7 S,
8 S, 9 S, T S, J S, Q S,
K S, A S

J S, 7 S, 9 D, A H, 2 C,
3 D, 5 D

2 C, 3 D, 5 D, 7 S, 9 D,
J S,A H
```

**Code:**

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        suits = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S']
        ranks = ['2', '3' , '4', '5', '6', '7' , '8', '9','T', 'J' , 'Q', 'K', 'A']
 
        self._cards = []
        self._deck = []
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self._deck.append(Card(rank, suit))
                
    def __str__(self):
        newDeck = []
        for card in range(0, len(self._deck), 5):
            newDeck.append(', '.join(str(i) for i in self._deck[card:card+5])) 
        return ',\n'.join(newDeck)       

class Hand(Deck):
    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = []
         
    def __str__(self):
        handShow = []
        for i in range(0, len(self._cards) , 5):
            handShow.append(', '.join(self._cards[i:i+5]))
        return ',\n'.join(handShow)
    
    def sort(self):     
        ordered = '23456789TJQKA'
        for i in self._cards:
            card = str(i)
            
        return sorted(card, key= ordered.index)
```

**The order of precedence is first rank = ['2', '3' , '4', '5', '6', '7' , '8', '9','T', 'J' , 'Q', 'K', 'A'] then suits precedence comes 2nd suit = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S']**

Comment: Can you include your `deck` class.

Comment: Here's another way to think about this problem.  Consider having your deck consist of the numbers from 0 to 51, and have a short function that translates a number into rank and suit.  Now, your sorting is easy.

Comment: @TimRoberts You mean create a comparison method?

Comment: No.  That's one short-term solution to your immediate problem, of course, but I'm suggesting that you consider having your card deck consist of integers.  0 would be 2C, through 51 which would be AS.